# How To Call Function Which Contains Parameter In Any Other Function Of Other Script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How To Call This Below Function In Any Other Function Of Any Other Script?

I Tried To Call This Function In Other Script Like This

```
grab.StartGrab();
```

but it is not working

```
public VRTK_ChildOfControllerGrabAttach other;

public void move()
{
    other.GetComponent<VRTK_ChildOfControllerGrabAttach>().StartGrab(//parameters here but how);
}
```

Here is the function

```
public override bool StartGrab(GameObject grabbingObject, GameObject givenGrabbedObject, Rigidbody givenControllerAttachPoint)
{
    if (base.StartGrab(grabbingObject, givenGrabbedObject, givenControllerAttachPoint))
    {
        SnapObjectToGrabToController(givenGrabbedObject);
        grabbedObjectScript.isKinematic = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `GetComponent<"ScriptName">.StartGrab()`, in which `ScriptName` is the name of the script that contains `StartGrab()`.

Note that as your method has 3 parameters, when you call it, you should pass them, or else you're gonna get compiler errors.

For example:

```
GetComponent<"ScriptName">.StartGrab(objectToGrab, grabbedObject, objectController);
```

You are now correctly calling the method. Note that `objectToGrab`, `grabbedObject` and `objectController` must be declared in the script you are calling the method, and must be type-equivalent as the parameters of `StartGrab()`.

Comment: as you can see that this function contains parameters when i call this function in any other script it shows compiler error that missing parameters or arguments

Comment: Yes, because when you call it, you should also inform the parameters that are required.

Comment: i tried your solution and it gives me this error " error CS1501: No overload for method `StartGrab' takes `0' arguments "

Comment: ok so how to pass those parameters which are part of this function

Comment: i tried and it gives me this error " error CS0103: The name `objectToGrab' does not exist in the current context " same error for other 2 parameters

Comment: This means that you haven't declared `objectToGrab` in the script you are calling the method. Please, read the last paragraph of my answer again and you'll understand why this is happening.

Comment: No, I haven't. It just seemed intuitive. 2 other notes: first, nowadays the word FUNCTION is not really used for object-oriented languages. You should use METHOD. Second, the comment section is for further information about questions or answer, and not for chat (as we are doing right now, unfortunately).

Comment: your `GetComponent<"ScriptName">` is kind of confusing ... `GetComponent<type>()` expects `type` to be a `System.Type` not a `string`.